# PC won't stay shutdown after power off when connected to UPS

Tags: windows-10, power-supply, shutdown

I'm running Win10 on a custom build that is connected to a UPC. When I shutdown the computer, it will fully shutdown, then start back up after a few seconds.

I've updated my BIOS to "Power Off" when power is reconnected to the chipset.

The UPC is an [APC Pro 1000 S](https://www.apc.com/us/en/product/BR1000MS/apc-backups-pro-1000s-1000va-120v-sinewave-avr-lcd-2-usb-charging-ports-10-nema-outlets-4-surge/).

Windows system event log just says that the OS was started with the last shutdown's success status and boot's status was true. Boot type is 0x0. Not sure what else the event log is telling me.

This behavior persists whether I perform `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe -s`, shutdown via task bar, or hold the power button.

Any ideas?

Edit: my motherboard is ASRock

Comment: Is there a mis-configured connection from the APC unit to the PC?   I have an APC unit and no issues doing a full and stable shutdown.  Otherwise the UPS is just an AC Supply and won't keep a shut down device ON.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check that. I have a cable running from the UPS to the computer so that the unit can communicate its power level. I installed powerchute just to disable alarms, then uninstalled it and reinstalled the Windows drivers to manage the battery level. Not sure where else I would check for misconfiguration.

Comment: I'm not experienced with UPSs, but what if you take the cable from the UPS and use that to plug your computer into the mains?  If the UPS is just sending power out the same as the mains wall outlet then there's no way the UPS can turn your computer on while the mains wall outlet doesn't. If the cable is the same. So try switching cables. I haven't used a UPS though.

Comment: The APC UPS has an integrated power cable. Like I said above too, this isn't an issue if my computer is plugged into the wall. I feel like this should be a BIOS issue, but I changed the config of my BIOS to stay off instead of power back on when power is reconnected. I don't remember what else in the BIOS would need to be changed for this.

Comment: The APC UPS has an integrated power cable   -- What does that mean?  I looked at the Unit and it looks like a normal AC cable to plug into an outlet.

Comment: I interpreted from your comment that you wanted me to try using the UPS’s power cable with my PC to see if the problem persisted?

Answer (score 0):

Computer now stays shutdown after it hit a bluescreen after a few days of being on/asleep. Don't know what caused the BS or what it reset, but I don't have the auto-restarts any more. Will update this post as I collect more info as I seriously doubt that anything was actually resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Its unclear to me too haha